# Matplotlib graphs are being duplicated each time

Tags: programming, qiskit

Simple UI question. I have installed qiskit according to the instruction and try to implement some basic operations. I have the issue that anything I plot appears twice. I am not sure why this is happening, so I am looking for some suggestions.

See the attached image:[image]

Comment: what happens if you put a semicolon at the end of your last line?

Comment: Oh damn, that fixes it. Why is this the case?

Comment: I'm not an expert in qiskit, but knowing python, I'd guess that the circuit.draw function is both drawing the circuit and returning it as output. Since it's the last line of your code, that return is also displayed. The semicolon just prevents that display of the return.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was an issue raised on qiskit-tutorials about this duplicate drawing. The solution that was done there was to remove `%matplotlib inline` from the notebooks.

If you would like to know more you can see the fix here https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/pull/1206 which also links back to issues which report the problem.